# Consecutive item comparison with smallest memory footprint

Tags: optimization, j, memory-optimization

In J (using J503, not J6 or 7), normally when I want to see if the elements of an array are smaller than their predecessor, I use this:

```
   smaller =: }:<:}.
```

Which results in n-1 items:

```
   smaller 1 2 3 4 5
1 1 1 1
   smaller 1 2 4 3
1 1 0
```

Internally, `}:` and `}.` create two arrays (one omits the last item, the other omits the first), finally allowing the `<:` comparison. The total memory usage will be `2(n-1)` for the 2 temp arrays.

```
   memuse =: 7!:2
   i =: ,(10000#1)?10000
   memuse 'smaller i'
148480
```

Another approach which should intuitively work better takes more memory:

```
   smaller2 =: 13 : '2<:/\y.'
   memuse 'smaller i'
214400
```

(J6 handles this much better. But I'm stuck with J5).

What would be a leaner alternative for the same operation?

Comment: And the reason why: arrays of sizes in the millions which need this. Looping over chunks of it sounds much more sane when I think about it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit:

In J504, using rotate (1|.) seems to be the best choice so far:

```
smallerS =: <:1&|.
l =: ?. 10000$1000
;memuse &.> 'smaller l';'smaller2 l';'smallerS l'
148480 214400 82880
```

---

I would expect

```
2<:/\y
```

to be **much** better, given that `2 f/\y` is [special code since J 4.06](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/release/infix2.htm). In the off chance that `<:` is the reason for the poor performance, try:

```
0>:2-/\ y
```

Comment: I would have expected '2<:/\y' to be much better too, and yet... I will benchmark the alternative you suggest.

Comment: It even says so in 4.06 release notes: _"2 f/\x is more efficient in time and space than the equivalent (}:x) f (}.x)"_ but I run the same benchmarks in j504 and it wasn't so. Something happened between j4 and j5 that made `f/\ ` worse than `{:f}.`. Also, try with rotate (new edit).

Comment: @MPelletier For J7 the results are `280576 18304 149248` for smaller, smaller2 and smallerS respectively. It is strange that `smaller` and `smallerS` perform so much worse in subsequent J versions.

Comment: `0>:2-/\ y` takes up 263552 bytes for my test, but your approach with rotate only takes 82880, in J503, same as J504. Impressive!